# Creation of Client mappers in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I have a question about mappers in keycloak.

We have to transmit the e-mail address in lower case.
In an older version, a “Mapper” tab was available for this purpose. This is now gone, but can be found via Client Scopes > dedicated Client Scope and “Mapper”.
However, we do not (any longer) find the option to transfer the email address with tolower().

Is there still a possibility to use this function, or a workaround?

Thank you in advance and have a great day :)
Best regards,
Melon

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a script mapper you have to use the option `--features scripts` and you must package your script in a jar file. You can find an example for example [here](https://www.bityard.org/blog/2022/04/21/keycloak_script_mapper)